# Input text into a program opened through terminal, but fast

Tags: python, linux, bash, input, output

I have a program which needs to receive input very fast and I know what the input has to be, but there is a timer which I suppose expects no delay between opening the program and entering the input.

I've tried using bash script but it doesn't seem to work, and trying ./program; password also doesn't work (it returns that 'password' is not a command).

My bash script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash 
cd ~/Downloads 
./program
password
```

Perhaps it's working, but I'm not receiving any output from the program, which would usually display how long it took to get an input.

Comment: Please show us what is in there in your `./program` in code tags?

Comment: In `./program; password`, `password` isn't passed as an argument to your program, you need `./program password`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, change execution to `~/Downloads/program password`. Also make sure program is executable ( `chmod +x` if it isn't) and that it takes arguments.

Furthermore, to refrain from mentioning the path every time, move program to `~/bin/` (create if it doesn't exist) and add that location to $PATH if it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If the "program" does not expect the password as a command line argument, then you probably want to input it through stdin:

```
#! /bin/bash 
cd ~/Downloads 
echo "password" | ./program
```

or, if there is more input:

```
./program <<INPUT
password
moreInput
moreInput2
...
moreInputN
INPUT
```

The first variant uses simple piping, the second relies on [HereDocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

In the (improbable) case that the program expects the password as an argument, you have to pass it as follows:

```
./programm password
```

without line-breaks and semicolons in between.

I'm saying that this is "improbable", because if such an invokation is used from the shell, then the password will be saved as clear text in bash-history, which is obviously not very good.